# Compile the Kotlin android file through the command line compiler, show unresolved reference: synthetic

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

I used kotlin-android-extensions
the kotlin code is simple

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        contentTV.text="new"
        Toast.makeText(this,"夸父注入成功22",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        println("hello world1234")
    }
}
```

I use the command:

kotlinc -classpath /Users/skateboard/AndroidStudioProjects/KuaFuTest/app/build/intermediates/javac/demoDebug/compileDemoDebugJavaWithJavac/classes:/Users/skateboard/AndroidStudioProjects/KuaFuTest/app/build/generated/source/apt/demo/debug:/Users/skateboard/AndroidStudioProjects/KuaFuTest/app/build/tmp/kotlin-classes/demoDebug:/Users/skateboard/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-android-extensions-runtime/1.4.0/98be06f8dfc5750d45b887d2b3330ef49390aeb7/kotlin-android-extensions-runtime-1.4.0.jar:/Users/skateboard/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/3e4b08cac9c41e8795af42a5b815b321/jars/classes.jar:/Users/skateboard/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.4.0/63e75298e93d4ae0b299bb869cf0c627196f8843/kotlin-stdlib-1.4.0.jar:/Users/skateboard/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.4.0/1c752cce0ead8d504ccc88a4fed6471fd83ab0dd/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.4.0.jar:/Users/skateboard/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains/annotations/13.0/919f0dfe192fb4e063e7dacadee7f8bb9a2672a9/annotations-13.0.jar:/Users/skateboard/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/8c61b603f350980f81417f4d3f853902/jars/classes.jar:/Users/skateboard/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/fe7696ac9a68e8ce0f0e0cc1b174b4c9/jars/classes.jar:/Users/skateboard/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/a0713d6b50505595f83734d3cfae9bed/jars/classes.jar:/Users/skateboard/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/925f9893c711f0c25548d940c9b7f168/jars/classes.jar:/Users/skateboard/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/b28b597b828d5b0aeacc49c107fd71db/jars/classes.jar:/Users/skateboard/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/10037c6171d23644c0b6060e1867b5a7/jars/classes.jar:/Users/skateboard/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/72f6b9e34a5eeae66c71ca9f86b4a6c3/jars/classes.jar:/Users/skateboard/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/9b40b231da712362bd8f03e85be0e8dd/jars/classes.jar:/Users/skateboard/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/4c94092ade43ee5bb6dd2adca8dd738d/jars/classes.jar:/Users/skateboard/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/ffa9732c899005350cbfd5e94b2e49f1/jars/classes.jar:/Users/skateboard/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/cfcfabbe3e4822088f431961ddb26265/jars/classes.jar:/Users/skateboard/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/f711abbaf1b6d3d1831f1a052db77b4f/jars/classes.jar:/Users/skateboard/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/d0fabd256c1613080926726dda0223e8/jars/classes.jar:/Users/skateboard/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/64ca1f0e2236ba245c5e08248d5aa195/jars/classes.jar:/Users/skateboard/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/907fc8f19fa97ba58e92a498b93f0e57/jars/classes.jar:/Users/skateboard/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/50ffe37981838fbb4bccc1654a350512/jars/classes.jar:/Users/skateboard/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/270ae6c5b28e9db49e35b2699e204e59/jars/classes.jar:/Users/skateboard/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/35a80db54afda52720cd558c2d512dac/jars/classes.jar:/Users/skateboard/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/6b3778bff2390065292489fa15d05f88/jars/classes.jar:/Users/skateboard/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/c5dc31390ef26854c632d1c31875ad52/jars/classes.jar:/Users/skateboard/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/5d6910a19b706ec657a4b8c64d20b5d0/jars/classes.jar:/Users/skateboard/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/267071f0ebeb7460627cedc63598d9f2/jars/classes.jar:/Users/skateboard/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.jakewharton/butterknife-annotations/10.2.3/45f0790cb0130b877d1269fc56e1a294b90dabc1/butterknife-annotations-10.2.3.jar:/Users/skateboard/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/809910e5428f0e79fda45e7c15454285/jars/classes.jar:/Users/skateboard/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/androidx.collection/collection/1.1.0/1f27220b47669781457de0d600849a5de0e89909/collection-1.1.0.jar:/Users/skateboard/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/24750ac89d4631677434276211cfdded/jars/classes.jar:/Users/skateboard/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/4346a3a0a738fa8458ff093199b5caa7/jars/classes.jar:/Users/skateboard/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/b60a76ab931c63b09190246a47776e74/jars/classes.jar:/Users/skateboard/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/d7e19ab7adc2577331058703432889ca/jars/classes.jar:/Users/skateboard/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/androidx.lifecycle/lifecycle-common/2.1.0/c67e7807d9cd6c329b9d0218b2ec4e505dd340b7/lifecycle-common-2.1.0.jar:/Users/skateboard/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/d032e6d96fe3ad1b9e9c73f1efdd0309/jars/classes.jar:/Users/skateboard/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/androidx.arch.core/core-common/2.1.0/b3152fc64428c9354344bd89848ecddc09b6f07e/core-common-2.1.0.jar:/Users/skateboard/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/492fba0096cb18fd2acb20d364f7892a/jars/classes.jar:/Users/skateboard/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/androidx.annotation/annotation/1.1.0/e3a6fb2f40e3a3842e6b7472628ba4ce416ea4c8/annotation-1.1.0.jar:/Users/skateboard/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/00650ab3c966493d1ba1f2b3849514c1/jars/classes.jar:/Users/skateboard/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/androidx.constraintlayout/constraintlayout-solver/2.0.4/1f001d7db280a89a6c26b26a66eb064bb6d5efeb/constraintlayout-solver-2.0.4.jar:/Users/skateboard/AndroidStudioProjects/KuaFuTest/mylibrary/build/intermediates/compile_library_classes/debug/classes.jar:/Users/skateboard/AndroidStudioProjects/KuaFuTest/kuafuapi/build/intermediates/compile_library_classes/debug/classes.jar:/Users/skateboard/AndroidStudioProjects/KuaFuTest/app/build/tmp/kapt3/classes/demoDebug:/Users/skateboard/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-30/android.jar -d /Users/skateboard/AndroidStudioProjects/KuaFuTest/app/build/kuafu/classes -**Xplugin=/Users/skateboard/.sdkman/candidates/kotlin/current/lib/android-extensions-compiler.jar** **-P plugin:org.jetbrains.kotlin.android:package=com.skateboard.kuafutest /Users/skateboard/AndroidStudioProjects/KuaFuTest/app/src/main/java/com/skateboard/kuafutest/MainActivity.kt**

It showed compile error:

```
app/src/main/java/com/skateboard/kuafutest/MainActivity.kt:7:24: error: unresolved reference: synthetic
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
                       ^
app/src/main/java/com/skateboard/kuafutest/MainActivity.kt:15:9: error: unresolved reference: contentTV
        contentTV.text="new"
        ^
app/src/main/java/com/skateboard/kuafutest/MainActivity.kt:15:19: error: variable expected
        contentTV.text="new"
                  ^
wujiaxin:KuaFuTest skateboard$
```

Comment: People usually use build systems instead of monster command line inputs. Have you tried using Gradle?

Comment: @Nicolas I know, but now I need to do some incremental compilation, and I need to use the command line to compile incremental files

Comment: Gradle also does incremental compilation.

Comment: @Nicolas I know,but it is too slow,so I need to do this by myself.I can reduce a lot of time

Comment: I'll be honest with you, I don't know if this is satire or not. How many hours have you spent doing this so far? How many more hours will it take? It simply isn't reasonable not to use a build system. Even if you manage to scrape a few extra seconds, I doubt it will have been worth the hassle. And how exactly do you hope to beat what a team of professional engineers have been doing at Gradle for several years in subject to incremental compilation?

Comment: The problem is not in the code snipped you posted but in the way you build your project. I would agree with Nicolas that a build tool would solve that problem for you.

Comment: @Nicolas I think gradle serves all teams, but our team has our own demands, so what I want to do is not to compete with gradle, I just want to make a solution that suits our team, so please pay attention to the problem itself, Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found the answer by decompiling the gradle compiler. When you want to compile and support kotlin-android-extensions on the command line, you need to add the parameter **-Xplugin=lib/android-extensions-compiler.jar -P plugin:org.jetbrains.kotlin .android:package=${package_name} -P plugin:org.jetbrains.kotlin.android:variant='${flovar};${resource_package}'**

Xplugin specifies the location of the jar package of the kotlin compiler plugin, flavor specifies the build variant such as main, and resource_package specifies the resource path such as /Users/dd/projectName/app/src/main/res